# Adding to one element in array results in adding to all elements

Tags: powershell, arraylist

I have the following:

```
$p = New-Object PSObject -Property @{PIndex = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList}
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$pa = @($p) * 5
```

I want the array $pa (containing the $p object) to be of fixed size. So far all looks good. But when I add elements to PIndex of one member of array $pa, it adds the same elements to all the other members of $pa.
So, I do this:

```
$pa[0].PIndex.Add(2)
```

Lets check:

```
PS C:\Users> $pa[0].PIndex
2
PS C:\Users> $pa[1].PIndex
2
PS C:\Users> $pa[2].PIndex
2
```

And so on. Just want to add elements to PIndex array of $pa[0]. Why is it also adding to the other members ? Am I missing a syntax ?

Type looks fine:

```
PS C:\Users> $pa.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                            
True     True     ArrayList                                System.Object
```

Thanks..

Comment: You're passing by reference instead of by value.  When you edit one, you edit them all.

Comment: Also, $pa is an arraylist not an array.

Comment: Reference/Value doesn't answer the question. Each member is distinct. I am pointing to a specific member. When I refer to $pa[0], I am not referring to $pa[1] or any other. Maybe the syntax..

Comment: I am using arraylist for a purpose. I just used the shorthand word array in the description. I know what the difference is..

Comment: Each is ***not*** distinct. that is why changing one is changing all. You have essentially added one object to the arraylist five times.

Comment: Do this if you want to add five different objects: `$pa = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;1..5 | %{$p =  New-Object PSObject -Property @{PIndex = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList}; $pa.Add($p)}`

Comment: @EBGreen please make a Answer for that response since thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you create **one** object ($p) then you assign that one object to five different locations in the arraylist. If you want five different objects then you need to create five different objects:

```
$pa = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
for($i=1;$i -le 5;$i++){
    $p = New-Object PSObject -Property @{PIndex = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList}
    $pa.Add($p)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.... will go with your suggestion (did have similar code with creating new object instances in a loop elsewhere in my program. Was trying to shortcut it with $pa = @($p) * 5 )...  :)